# How to map Addresses class with list of Address in EmployeeMap using Mybatis?

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis

**How to map Addresses class with list of Address in EmployeeMap using Mybatis? is my code below correct? **

Below is query is to get employeeId and hos multiple address locations. How to map those fields in MyBatis? Appreciate your help to map the fields. FYI, I could not post complete Address class with other fields

```
<resultMap id="EmployeeMap" type="Employee">
    <result column="emplId" property="emplId"/>
    <collection property="addressList" >
        <result column="addressLineOne" property="addressLineOne"/>
        <result column="addressLineTwo" property="addressLineTwo"/>
        <result column="city" property="city"/>
        <result column="country" property="country"/>
        <result column="zipCode" property="zipCode"/>
    </collection>
 </resultMap>
 <select id="employeeData" resultMap="EmployeeMap">Select * from employee</select>
```

**Here is My Java code**

```
public class Employee{

    String emplId;
    Addresses addressList;

    public String getEmplId() {
        return emplId;
    }

   public void setEmplId(Addresses value) {
        this.emplId = value;
   }


   public Addresses getAddressList() {
       return addressList;
   }

   public void setAddressList(Addresses value) {
       this.addressList = value;
   }
}
public class Addresses{

   List<Address> addresses;

   public List<Address> getAddresses() {
     if (addresses == null) {
        addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
      }
     return this.addresses;
   }
 }
 public class Address{
   String city;

  public String getCity(){
       return city;
   }

   public void setCity(String value) {
       this.city = value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target property of `<collection />` is `addressList.addresses`, so the result map should look as follows:

```xml
<resultMap id="EmployeeMap" type="Employee">
  <id column="emplId" property="emplId"/>
  <collection property="addressList.addresses"
      javaType="list" ofType="Address">
    <result column="addressLineOne" property="addressLineOne"/>
    <result column="addressLineTwo" property="addressLineTwo"/>
    <result column="city" property="city"/>
    <result column="country" property="country"/>
    <result column="zipCode" property="zipCode"/>
  </collection>
</resultMap>
```

Note: You should specify `<id />` in the parent result map.

Comment: Thank you, It helped

Comment: This is adding only first record to the address list and ignoring all other records

Comment: @SandeepM Wrote a quick demo for you. https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/so-61093582/so-61093582

Comment: HI thanks for the response, I found the issue, it is not because of MyBatis, it is because of chunk size in my SpringBatch

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for letting me know!